# Translate the Flash Message

Tags: forms, translation, symfony, flash-message

I'm trying to translate the flash message I sent, if a form is succesful. 
The normal request looks like this:

```
$request->getSession()->getFlashBag()->add(
            'notice',
            'Your E-Mail has been sent.'
        );
```

So I tried to translate the message with the following variable:

```
$request->getSession()->getFlashBag()->add(
            'notice',
            'contact.message.email_has_been_sent'
        );
```

After sending the form the message shows "contact.message.email_has_been_sent". So it didn't found the translation, but the variable is right. I tested it inside a template file. 
Has anyone an idea, how I could fix this? I didn't found anything useful yet.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Presuming you are in a Controller:

```
$request->getSession()->getFlashBag()->add(
    'notice',
    $this->get('translator')->trans('contact.message.email_has_been_sent'));
```

Read how to handle [Translations](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/translation.html).

Comment: Since SF 2.8, you can simply do $this->addFlash().

Comment: @VictorToulouse this is not the point of the question, but what if you don't extend the base controller of the FrameworkExtraBundle? Anyway I agree that I should expand my very "old" answer to cover all the way offered by the framework :-)

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively, in twig:

```
{% for flashMessage in app.session.flashbag.get('notice') %}
    <p>{{ flashMessage|trans }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I would tend to prefer this method as it makes calling the translator from the controller unnecessary, but it gets complicated when you need to translate messages with placeholders.

Comment: See possible problems with this approach here: https://coderwall.com/p/ybup5a/symfony2-translating-flash-messages

Answer (score 0):

In Symfony 5, you should inject TranslatorInterface and call trans() method passing the message id, for example:

```
public function method(TranslatorInterface $translator)
{
    $translator->trans('Message Id'); 
}
```