# Getting the translation text on Symfony controller

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1

I have translation file named as `messages.en.yml` file on the location `<My-Bundle>/Resources/translations` as follow:

```
company:
    messages:
        schedule:
            success:  Schedule saved successfully
            failed:   Something went wrong on saving schedule
```

Now I need to call this message by key on here:

```
$this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add(
    'success',
    '%company.messages.schedule.success%'
);
```

I try many ways but not able to fix this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Translate the Flash Message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28588839/translate-the-flash-message)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it is **impossible** to translate a key translation in the flash bag ...

You could create a custom service with as dependencies

- Translator
- The session

And then perform the translation yourself before adding the message to the flashBag

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Flash\FlashBag;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;
use Symfony\Component\Translation\Translator;

class FlashBagTranslator
{
    /** @var Translator $translator */
    private $translator;

    /** @var FlashBag $flashBag */
    private $flashBag;

    public function __construct(Translator $translator, Session $session)
    {
        $this->translator = $translator;
        $this->flashBag = $session->getFlashBag();
    }

    public function addMessage($type, $translationKey, array $parameters = [], $domain = null, $locale = null)
    {
        $message = $this->translator->trans($translationKey, $parameters, $domain, $locale);
        if ($message === $translationKey) {
            // Your translation isn't findable, do something :)
            return false;
        }

        $this->flashBag->add($type, $message);
        return true;
    }
}
```

A little disappointing, isn't it ?

Comment: yes. I think so. But i don't have any reference how to adding the translation on the flashbags

Comment: I'll add some code to my answer, let me some minutes :)

Comment: @nifCody you didn't validate the answer :/

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
$this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add(
'success',
$this->get('translator')->trans('company.messages.schedule.success')
);
```

also, need to enable in configuration:

```
framework:
    default_locale: 'en'
    translator:
        fallbacks: ['en']
```

Check official documentation: [Symfony Basic Translation](http://symfony.com/doc/master/translation.html#basic-translation)

Comment: no it is not working. It returns company.messages.schedule.success